# How give a input stream (Parameter) class constructor a default argument value?

Tags: c++11

Question: temp class (istream) constructor can be called by giving an input stream object but I want to called that (istream) constructor with zero argument or you can say I want to give (istream) construct a default argument. How I can do this?

```
#include <iostream>

class temp
{
public:
    temp(std::istream &is) { is >> i; }
private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    temp obj(std::cin); // okay

 /* 
  *  temp obj; // error:temp object don;t take zero argument // but i want this!
  */
}
```

Comment: Add a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) for this.
e.g. [Ideone Link](https://ideone.com/hjIEpf)

```
#include <iostream>

class temp
{
public:
    temp(std::istream &is = std::cin ) { is >> i; }
private:
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    temp obj(std::cin); // okay
    temp obj1; // error:temp object don;t take zero argument // but i want this!
  
}
```

Comment: What would be the default stream?

Comment: @TanveerBadar added the example.